# How to show regexp parts of text

Tags: bash, regex, find

I've lots of files which lines looks like

```
lotsofblah/XY##_####_morefoo
```

where # is a number. Now i want to show only the parts

```
YZ##_####
```

in the bash, each in a new line of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want XY to be any two letters...

Something like

```
grep -Eo "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}" file
```

Would match [two letters][two numbers]_[four numbers]

If you wanted, it could be a little more exact, making sure there's a / infront and a _ afterwards, but this is a starting point.

Put this together from man grep:

> ```
> -E, --extended-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below)
>
> -o, --only-matching
>           Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
> ```

and http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that XY and YZ are the same, and I'll treat them just as XY

```
egrep "XY[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}" filename -o
```

The key is the `-o` option that shows only the matching text.